# Is there a way to send commands from a website to an Android app

Tags: python, android, web, trading

Am working on this python project that automates trading.
But I don't know how to get data from a trading indicator website and give a specific command to an App on Android.
Anyone who can help me out......

Answer (score 0):

You'd use push notifications like FCM to send a message from the server to the android device.  Your app can then read the message and react appropriately.